# Renaming javascript objects on the basis of match and overwrite the old object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having an array for which i m calculating the count of every unique array element.
array is stored as arr after that i have used a created a function to calculate the values of all uniques.

```
<script>
var arr = [ '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  ]
arr1 = arr.sort()
var uniqs = arr1.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = acc[val] === undefined ? 1 : acc[val] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(uniqs)

</script>
```

what i get

```
<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>: 1
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>: 11
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>: 1
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a>: 1
<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>: 3
```

and i want something like this

Web Client: 1
Android: 11
iPhone: 1
Facebook: 1
Web App: 3

Comment: its not a code writing service, post an attempt, so that someone can analyse and help you find the issue.

Comment: I think this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While HTML is not a regular language (see meme-ish reference here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), from those short tags you can really extract what you want using regex:

```js
var arr = [ '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  ];
  
arr.forEach(function(tag){
  console.log(tag);
  console.log(tag.match(/<a.*>(Twitter )?(for )?(.*)<\/a>/)[3]);
});
```

([`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) produces an array, containing the entire match in `[0]`, and the groups in parentheses, so `[1]` is for `Twitter` and `[2]` is for `for`, or `undefined` when they are not present, and `[3]` is what you need).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your initial question( assuming queries stored in an object)
you can do something like

```
var object = {'<a href="http://kaptaankohli.com" rel="nofollow">The Gujarat Lions FC</a>': 15,'<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>': 1};


for (var key in object) {
if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var regex = /\>(.*?)\</;
var matched = regex.exec(key);
console.log(matched[1]);
//insert matched[1], object[key] into a new object
}
};
```